# Keep vertex and fragment shader from glsl.heroku.com

Tags: android, opengl-es

I found this amazing effects on http://glsl.heroku.com/e#3265.2
I need to use it in an android based app (the engine that I use is rajawali) so I need both vertex and fragment shader. As I understand the code that I see is the fragment shader... but where I can found or generate the vertex shader?

Comment: Well, if you look very closely at the fragment shader you will notice that it does not rely on any `varying`s at all. The only input it uses (aside from the uniforms: `time` and `resolution`) is `gl_FragCoord`, and this is implicitly generated immediately before the fragment shader starts. Effectively, you can use a dummy vertex shader that just passes some vertices through - you probably want to draw a fullscreen quad so you could define those vertices in NDC space for the four corners of the screen. You do have to know what `time` and `resolution` represent though; I cannot help you there.

Comment: OK , I have understand. I found however a vertex code in the source code of the page... but when i use it the engine it doesn't work ..
Can you help me to create one to use in my engine? Thanks :)